# Can heat cause the excitation of argon

Tags: heat, noble-gases

Can argon be excited by heating? I work with a process that involves heating titanium to 500c-1000c in an argon environment. On our camera, the material looks purple when heated, the same shade as excited argon. It doesn't show with the naked eye but potentially the camera is seeing something that we cannot. Odds are this is just a camera malfunction but it's interesting to think that there is some process at work here.

Comment: How is the titanium being heated exactly? If there is an electrical discharge involved, then excited argon atoms are possible.

Comment: I think it's much too low temperature.

Comment: Is the camera calibrated? A digital cameras job is to give an image not necessarily accurate.

Comment: @EdV the heat source is from friction

Comment: Interesting! Can you put a cheap plastic transmission diffraction grating in front of the camera, to look for possible argon atomic emission lines? Or just use the grating and view by eye? I happen to be working with the argon emission spectrum (in the 400 to 700 nm range), so I will test what I just suggested using several argon lamps/discharge tubes.

Comment: Stir welding/fusion? At the point of contact, 1. there can be local hot-spots, perhaps enough to ionize Ar, and 2. If there were an oxide coating, there could be triboelectric effect (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect), though I doubt there would be in the bulk metal. BTW, triboelectricity also explains earthquake-related lightning: https://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/201406/earthquake.cfm\